# base64 encoded iv? (NSISCrypt) Symmetric Encryption

Tags: encryption, base64, nsis

So im trying to use a plugin called NSISCrypt for a NSIS Installer, Im wanting to obfuscate a register password.

So there are some easy Base64 encryption and decryption. So I thought HEY! great....
http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NsisCrypt_plug-in (He is the Readme for it)

Problem is Im not really sure what the Base64 iv is.....i've googled base64 iv and have come up with nothing.

Im not expert at encryption, however I understand what a Preshared Key is of course.....but what would a BaseIV be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An [initialization vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector) is a non secret, typically unique or random, generated data to help make encryption non deterministic when the same key is used. The docs there are just saying the IV needs to be base64 encoded.